# How to get the content of web page?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading web page by sending username & password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397332/reading-web-page-by-sending-username-password)

My problem is this. There is a site that has data which is frequently updated that I would like to get at regular intervals for later reporting.

for getting that data i have to provide the userid & password.

I have used HttpWebRequest to get data but the problem is that response text returns "Your browser doesn't support frame" instead of the data i want.

how can i get it?

Comment: You asked this exact question 19 hours ago: [Reading web page by sending username & password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397332/reading-web-page-by-sending-username-password)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are having this problem because you are not setting the user-agent in your request, i.e. with a `WebClient`:

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
    string htmlResult = wc.DownloadString(someUrl);
}
```

Comment: I have used your code but same error occurred "<p class=MsoNormal>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support
  them.</p>"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx) control to solve your problem. This approach works like this, First, you have to load the specific webpage on to the WebBrowser Control, then once the document has been [loaded or not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.isbusy.aspx) .  If loaded then you can retrieve the web page stream using [DocumentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) property.

Hope this helps.